# How to set the url in off-line site using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, static-site

well my task is running a static site, No servers at all. pure HTML, and i need to load and read an XML file and update the page with the result.

The task is done and can read the xml file if the file is in the same location, the problem is if the xml file is in a separate folder the ajax flails. seems like the url fails.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",

  // working url setting - case - 1
  // url: "somexmlfile.xml",

  // not working - case - 2
  url: "../somepath/somexmlfile.xml",

  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml){
    // do something with the returned data
  },
  error: function() {
    // display the error
  }
});
```

Case - 1 is the working solution for me, but i need to place the xml file in a separate place.

Then the case - 2 is the way to get to the file which is getting failed.

any idea,

Actually no domain, no servers, its is pure HTML,

All files are in ex:

**D:/myfiles/someFolder/index.html**

If i put the file in

**D:/myfiles/someFolder/xml/myxml.xml** 
and set the url as

**url: "xml/myxml.xml"**

this config is working too,

But i'm trying to place the xml file in

**D:/myfiles/xml/myxml.xml** and need to read the file using ajax setting the url as

**url: "../xml/myxml.xml"**

Comment: I hope that you know the meaning of "../somepath/somexmlfile.xml", it will get you to previous folder where your current file is and then it will take you into "somepath" folder and then it will look for the file "somexmlfile.xml"

Comment: yes it is, but it can not locate to the file, i am afraid without a server this can be done?

Comment: Any suggestion from any one please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was to turn off browser security (strict_origin_policy set to false on about:config) on Firefox settings and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an absolute url:

```
www.yourdomain.ext/siteDolder/xmlFolder/xmlfile.xml
```

Comment: Actually no domain, no servers, its is pure HTML,

Comment: I hope you needs to provide the domains physical path of your file. Where did you hosted/deployed your files or using a local machine?

Comment: actually it is will say index.html file is in D:/myfiles/someFolder/index.html

Comment: I think it's a CORS problem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing ). It occurs because your xml file is "outside" your index.html folder